# IText HTML to PDF memory leak

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xmlworker

Good Day,

I'm using itext to convert HTML to PDF. But when it invokes the `XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);` its becoming slow and when I check JVisualVM, it seems that there is a memory leak.

Here is my code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);        
    document.open();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);

    document.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
```

Its running on Tomcat server.

Here is the html code:

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<html>
 <head> 
    <title>Title</title>
    
   
 </head> 
    
<body>  
  
      
EXAMPLE

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely not a memory leak but merely a situation in which much memory is used. Or do you have any indication of an actual memory *leak* in contrast to mere memory *usage*.

Comment: Can you give some stats on Memory usage? How big is the document? Like 1-2 A4 pages or more like several hundreds? Are pictures involved?

Comment: @mkl I think you are right. when I check the JavaVisualVM. the heap size is 500MB and when XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is); invokes. the heap size reach the Max of 2GB. but the used heap is only around 500MB below..

Comment: @Fildor its only 1 page of plaint text.

Comment: 2 GB sound extreme for a single page of plain text. Can you share the page HTML (and referenced resources if applicable) to reproduce the issue? And can you tell which JRE is used, i.e. build (Oracle? Open? IBM? ...?) and version? Are there any non-default garbage collection related settings in use? And are the 2 GB used for a single conversion or are there multiple, concurrent ones?

Comment: @mkl im using Jdk1.7.0_79. and using tomcat 7. U paste the html code

Comment: Ok, that many gigs for that bit of HTML is a bit too much...

Comment: @mkl yes. and the previous implementation is working fine. the previous is just getting the pdf from a webservice. but right now I need to convert an HTML to pdf. but when I use itext it happens.

Comment: I just executed your code with your sample HTML string 5 times in a loop with a small `sleep` in-between and observed the JRE heap size in JVisualVM. The heap never exceeded 100 MB, and the used heap remained clearly below 50 MB all the time. Furthermore, the first time it was executed took 428ms, the following times less than 100ms each. Thus, the cause of your memory issues is not the code you posted, at least not in combination with the given HTML.

Comment: (Admittedly I used 1.7.0_67, the latest 1.7.0 version I had at hands.)

Comment: @mkl thank you for the simulation. Anyway, is there any impact if the code is inside a servlet?

Comment: @Develofer In general there shouldn't be. A servlet container may cancel servlet calls taking to much resources but in the case at hand the required resources are small. A servlet container may run with different garbage collection settings but that shouldn't make a difference for a single call of your code. I would propose debugging the servlet call, in particular stepping a bit into the `XmlWorker`method calls.

Answer (score 0):

For Maven projects: Add the following dependency to your project’s pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
    import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;

    public class HtmlToPdf {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
            File htmlFile = new File(args[0]);
            String pdfFileName = "test.pdf";
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            if (htmlFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(htmlFile);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(pdfFileName);
                    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
                    document.open();
                    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);             
                    System.out.println("PDF Created!");
                } finally {

                    // close the document before before input stream (is) and writer closure                
                    if(document != null && document.isOpen()) {
                        document.close();
                    }

                    // no harm in closing writer here
                    if(writer != null) {
                        writer.close();
                    }
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi. there is no parameter for PDFWriter in closeQuietly

Comment: I was expecting it to be the sub-class of Writer, If it is not then writer.close() can be called in finally if it's not null.

Comment: Not closing `document` is a no-go in iText 5.x. Empty `catch` clauses are in general. Have you tested your code at all? That being said, it indeed is a good idea to close one's streams.

Comment: Sorry I haven't run this code. This code is just to describe the stream closure generally to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Closing one's streams is important. But if you want to get a point across using code, you had better verify it works because people assume code in answers to be runnable, not merely educational; whenever you cannot check that (e.g. if answering from a smart phone without IDE), you had better describe your ideas in words. (And even tested code is improved by some accompanying describing words...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the code to make it runnable  without any further modification.